# Wireguard peer loses VPN IP address after connection, but stays connected to VPN server and can ping the server IP on Ubuntu Server. How to fix?

Tags: ubuntu, wireguard, ubuntu-22.04, vpn-client

I am tunneling an Ubuntu 22.04 web server through a Wireguard VPN (as the vpn client), to  another Ubuntu 22.04 Server as the Wireguard VPN Host (server). I have set up the Client/Server exactly according to [these instructions from Linuxbabe](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/wireguard-vpn-server-ubuntu) with port forwarding and masquerading on the WG server enabled. I am also running unbound DNS on my WG Client. Both my WG Client and WG Server are running Ubuntu 22.04.

When I connect my VPN Client using `sudo systemctl start wg-quick@wg-client0.service` and `sudo systemctl enable wg-quick@wg-client0.service`, my client successfully connects to the wireguard server.

When connected to the tunnel `10.10.10.1` is the private IP address for the VPN server and `10.10.10.2` is the Private IP address of the VPN Client. I can successfully ping `10.10.10.1` from the client indicating that the VPN connection is successful.

I then run `curl https://icanhazip.com` on the wireguard client, and it successfully shows that I am using the IP address of the Wireguard Server. Great! Right? Well, Not exactly.

It only takes about a minute or so before the wireguard client loses the IP address of the server. After a minute of being successfully connected to the tunnel, I again try the commmand `curl https://icanhazip.com`, which now returns my home's public IP address, NOT the IP address of the wireguard Server.

However, it still appears that even though I am using my home IP address, I am still connected to the WG Server somehow, because when I run the command `systemctl status wg-quick@wg0.service` it returns the following:

```
● wg-quick@wg-client0.service - WireGuard via wg-quick(8) for wg/client0
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/wg-quick@.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Thu 2024-03-14 22:12:48 CDT; 17min ago
       Docs: man:wg-quick(8)
             man:wg(8)
             https://www.wireguard.com/
             https://www.wireguard.com/quickstart/
             https://git.zx2c4.com/wireguard-tools/about/src/man/wg-quick.8
             https://git.zx2c4.com/wireguard-tools/about/src/man/wg.8
    Process: 11681 ExecStart=/usr/bin/wg-quick up wg-client0 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 11681 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 364ms
```

Furthermore, a `ping 10.10.10.1` is STILL successful after I noticed my IP address is using my home IP. So somehow, my WG client is connecting to the WG Server, but is not using the WG Server's IP address.

Here are my Wireguard Logs on the WG Client:

```
sudo dmesg -wH | grep wireguard
[  +4.964216] wireguard: wg-client0: Keypair 56 destroyed for peer 6
[  +0.000031] wireguard: wg-client0: Keypair 57 destroyed for peer 6
[  +0.145173] wireguard: wg-client0: Peer 6 (123.45.678.9:51820) destroyed
[  +0.048057] wireguard: wg-client0: Interface destroyed
[  +2.575997] wireguard: wg-client0: Interface created
[  +0.022138] wireguard: wg-client0: Peer 7 created
[  +0.040251] wireguard: wg-client0: Sending keepalive packet to peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
[  +0.000055] wireguard: wg-client0: Sending handshake initiation to peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
[  +0.054499] wireguard: wg-client0: Receiving handshake response from peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
[  +0.000047] wireguard: wg-client0: Keypair 58 created for peer 7
[  +2.921467] wireguard: wg-client0: Sending handshake initiation to peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
[  +0.036876] wireguard: wg-client0: Receiving handshake response from peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
[  +0.000068] wireguard: wg-client0: Keypair 59 created for peer 7
[  +0.000038] wireguard: wg-client0: Sending keepalive packet to peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
[  +4.844707] wireguard: wg-client0: Sending keepalive packet to peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
[  +5.255566] wireguard: wg-client0: Sending keepalive packet to peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
[  +4.426967] wireguard: wg-client0: Sending handshake initiation to peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
[  +0.017808] wireguard: wg-client0: Receiving handshake response from peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
[  +0.000070] wireguard: wg-client0: Keypair 58 destroyed for peer 7
[  +0.000021] wireguard: wg-client0: Keypair 60 created for peer 7
[  +0.000033] wireguard: wg-client0: Sending keepalive packet to peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
[  +4.643183] wireguard: wg-client0: Sending keepalive packet to peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
[  +1.076531] wireguard: wg-client0: Sending keepalive packet to peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
[  +0.694589] wireguard: wg-client0: Sending keepalive packet to peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
[  +0.000355] wireguard: wg-client0: Sending handshake initiation to peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
[  +0.040759] wireguard: wg-client0: Receiving handshake response from peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
[  +0.000061] wireguard: wg-client0: Keypair 59 destroyed for peer 7
[  +0.000021] wireguard: wg-client0: Keypair 61 created for peer 7
[  +0.000031] wireguard: wg-client0: Sending keepalive packet to peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
[  +4.597413] wireguard: wg-client0: Sending keepalive packet to peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
[  +4.753398] wireguard: wg-client0: Sending keepalive packet to peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
[  +0.000386] wireguard: wg-client0: Sending handshake initiation to peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
[  +0.019951] wireguard: wg-client0: Receiving handshake response from peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
[  +0.000053] wireguard: wg-client0: Keypair 60 destroyed for peer 7
[  +0.000020] wireguard: wg-client0: Keypair 62 created for peer 7
[  +0.000030] wireguard: wg-client0: Sending keepalive packet to peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
[  +5.165602] wireguard: wg-client0: Sending keepalive packet to peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
[  +4.296682] wireguard: wg-client0: Sending keepalive packet to peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
[  +0.000218] wireguard: wg-client0: Sending handshake initiation to peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
[  +0.026552] wireguard: wg-client0: Receiving handshake response from peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
[  +0.000048] wireguard: wg-client0: Keypair 61 destroyed for peer 7
[  +0.000015] wireguard: wg-client0: Keypair 63 created for peer 7
[  +0.000023] wireguard: wg-client0: Sending keepalive packet to peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
[  +4.707453] wireguard: wg-client0: Sending keepalive packet to peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
[  +2.242105] wireguard: wg-client0: Sending keepalive packet to peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
[  +0.736789] wireguard: wg-client0: Sending handshake initiation to peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
[  +0.018656] wireguard: wg-client0: Receiving handshake response from peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
[  +0.000055] wireguard: wg-client0: Keypair 62 destroyed for peer 7
[  +0.000017] wireguard: wg-client0: Keypair 64 created for peer 7
[  +0.000028] wireguard: wg-client0: Sending keepalive packet to peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
[  +3.992663] wireguard: wg-client0: Sending keepalive packet to peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
[  +0.736520] wireguard: wg-client0: Sending handshake initiation to peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
[  +0.006477] wireguard: wg-client0: Receiving handshake response from peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
[  +0.000041] wireguard: wg-client0: Keypair 63 destroyed for peer 7
[  +0.000013] wireguard: wg-client0: Keypair 65 created for peer 7
[  +0.000020] wireguard: wg-client0: Sending keepalive packet to peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
[  +4.557038] wireguard: wg-client0: Sending keepalive packet to peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
[  +4.711950] wireguard: wg-client0: Sending keepalive packet to peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
[  +0.737920] wireguard: wg-client0: Sending handshake initiation to peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
[  +0.007975] wireguard: wg-client0: Receiving handshake response from peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
[  +0.000059] wireguard: wg-client0: Keypair 64 destroyed for peer 7
[  +0.000021] wireguard: wg-client0: Keypair 66 created for peer 7
[  +0.000030] wireguard: wg-client0: Sending keepalive packet to peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
[  +4.865521] wireguard: wg-client0: Sending keepalive packet to peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
[  +4.251146] wireguard: wg-client0: Sending keepalive packet to peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
[  +1.737488] wireguard: wg-client0: Sending handshake initiation to peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
[  +0.008468] wireguard: wg-client0: Receiving handshake response from peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
[  +0.000055] wireguard: wg-client0: Keypair 65 destroyed for peer 7
[  +0.000019] wireguard: wg-client0: Keypair 67 created for peer 7
[  +0.000025] wireguard: wg-client0: Sending keepalive packet to peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
[  +4.406383] wireguard: wg-client0: Sending keepalive packet to peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
[  +4.561784] wireguard: wg-client0: Sending keepalive packet to peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
[  +1.734768] wireguard: wg-client0: Sending handshake initiation to peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
[  +0.008146] wireguard: wg-client0: Receiving handshake response from peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
[  +0.000075] wireguard: wg-client0: Keypair 66 destroyed for peer 7
[  +0.000025] wireguard: wg-client0: Keypair 68 created for peer 7
[  +0.000036] wireguard: wg-client0: Sending keepalive packet to peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
[  +4.717223] wireguard: wg-client0: Sending keepalive packet to peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)

sudo journalctl -kf | grep wireguard

Mar 14 22:34:59 mail.example.com kernel: wireguard: wg-client0: Sending keepalive packet to peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
Mar 14 22:35:04 mail.example.com kernel: wireguard: wg-client0: Sending handshake initiation to peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
Mar 14 22:35:04 mail.example.com kernel: wireguard: wg-client0: Receiving handshake response from peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
Mar 14 22:35:04 mail.example.com kernel: wireguard: wg-client0: Keypair 67 destroyed for peer 7
Mar 14 22:35:04 mail.example.com kernel: wireguard: wg-client0: Keypair 69 created for peer 7
Mar 14 22:35:04 mail.example.com kernel: wireguard: wg-client0: Sending keepalive packet to peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
Mar 14 22:35:59 mail.example.com kernel: wireguard: wg-client0: Sending keepalive packet to peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
Mar 14 22:36:59 mail.example.com kernel: wireguard: wg-client0: Sending keepalive packet to peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
Mar 14 22:37:04 mail.example.com kernel: wireguard: wg-client0: Sending handshake initiation to peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
Mar 14 22:37:04 mail.example.com kernel: wireguard: wg-client0: Receiving handshake response from peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
Mar 14 22:37:04 mail.example.com kernel: wireguard: wg-client0: Keypair 68 destroyed for peer 7
Mar 14 22:37:04 mail.example.com kernel: wireguard: wg-client0: Keypair 70 created for peer 7
Mar 14 22:37:04 mail.example.com kernel: wireguard: wg-client0: Sending keepalive packet to peer 7 (123.45.678.9:51820)
```

Here is my syslog after starting the wireguard client:

```
Mar 15 14:32:19 mail systemd[1]: Starting WireGuard via wg-quick(8) for wg/client0...
Mar 15 14:32:19 mail wg-quick[18019]: [#] ip link add wg-client0 type wireguard
Mar 15 14:32:19 mail wg-quick[18019]: [#] wg setconf wg-client0 /dev/fd/63
Mar 15 14:32:19 mail networkd-dispatcher[1125]: WARNING:Unknown index 24 seen, reloading interface list
Mar 15 14:32:19 mail systemd-udevd[18030]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v249'.
Mar 15 14:32:19 mail NetworkManager[1121]: <info>  [1710531139.4647] manager: (wg-client0): new WireGuard device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/24)
Mar 15 14:32:19 mail wg-quick[18019]: [#] ip -4 address add 10.10.10.2/24 dev wg-client0
Mar 15 14:32:19 mail wg-quick[18019]: [#] ip link set mtu 1420 up dev wg-client0
Mar 15 14:32:19 mail systemd-networkd[1075]: wg-client0: Link UP
Mar 15 14:32:19 mail systemd-networkd[1075]: wg-client0: Gained carrier
Mar 15 14:32:19 mail wg-quick[18049]: [#] resolvconf -a tun.wg-client0 -m 0 -x
Mar 15 14:32:19 mail wg-quick[18019]: [#] wg set wg-client0 fwmark 51820
Mar 15 14:32:19 mail wg-quick[18019]: [#] ip -4 route add 0.0.0.0/0 dev wg-client0 table 51820
Mar 15 14:32:19 mail wg-quick[18019]: [#] ip -4 rule add not fwmark 51820 table 51820
Mar 15 14:32:19 mail wg-quick[18019]: [#] ip -4 rule add table main suppress_prefixlength 0
Mar 15 14:32:19 mail wg-quick[18019]: [#] sysctl -q net.ipv4.conf.all.src_valid_mark=1
Mar 15 14:32:19 mail wg-quick[18076]: [#] iptables-restore -n
Mar 15 14:32:19 mail systemd[1]: Finished WireGuard via wg-quick(8) for wg/client0.
Mar 15 14:34:01 mail CRON[18302]: (root) CMD (for ((i=1; i<=6; i++)) do (ping -c9 10.10.10.1 > /dev/null || systemctl restart wg-quick@wg-client0.service) done )
Mar 15 14:35:13 mail wpa_supplicant[10176]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Mar 15 14:35:13 mail systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Mar 15 14:35:13 mail dbus-daemon[1120]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Mar 15 14:35:13 mail systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Mar 15 14:35:17 mail systemd-networkd[1075]: wlan0: Connected WiFi access point: 'danswifi' (61:39:a0:c3:d1:a2)
Mar 15 14:35:17 mail wpa_supplicant[10176]: wlan0: Associated with 61:39:a0:c3:d1:a2
Mar 15 14:35:17 mail wpa_supplicant[10176]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 61:39:a0:c3:d1:a2 completed [id=0 id_str=]
Mar 15 14:35:17 mail wpa_supplicant[10176]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
```

Here is my Netplan configuration at `/etc/netplan/Ethernet+WiFi.yaml`

```
network:
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp4-overrides:
        route-metric: 100
      optional: true
  renderer: networkd
  version: 2
  wifis:
    renderer: networkd
    wlan0:
      access-points:
        1Jerk:
          password: *********************************************************
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp4-overrides:
        route-metric: 200
      optional: true
```

Could someone please help me figure out why my WG Client keeps losing its VPN IP address, but still remains connected to the WG Server somehow? Could you please help me fix this so that the IP address of the WG Client is persistently that of the WG Server IP address?

I'm pretty clueless here and don't see much in the logs.

Comment: could be a misconfiguration in the `.conf` file of either end - `the IP address of the WG Client is persistently that of the WG Server IP` makes no sense, i.e. two "devices" with the same IP on the same network segment

Comment: An other networking tool on your client is probably interfering. Before starting the tunnel,  keep this running on the client: `ip -ts monitor`. It will be verbose. Once the failure happens, check what happened in ip monitor's logs. If you report them in the question, please filter them out to keep only useful parts. You'll have to compare this to other system logs to figure out what other tool interferes.